# Are Windows viruses recognized by AppArmor or SELinux?

Tags: wine, security, malware, apparmor, selinux

I know windows and Linux are completely different environments but are there developers that implement the recognition of windows viruses in AppArmor or SELinux?
I'd like it so you don't have to scan every file you download with ClamAV and it could help people to know instantly if there are infected files on their devices by showing a popup (a daemon that warns you) so you are sure you could transfer them to windows.

Maybe implementing the recognition of these viruses it could improve security by studying how every single windows virus could affect Linux in a similar way even though I know .exe files could be launched only through Wine.

What I mean is to preemtivly study the way a windows virus behaves on windows and then block its code even on Linux. This could improve security on Wine if not even block the rising of new viruses that in similar ways could affect Linux.

Comment: AppArmor and SELinux are designed for application isolation and protection of key system components - they aren't designed to recognize Windows viruses or similar.  No 'virus' is going to be recognized by AppArmor or SELinux as a virus.  As long as there's a profile restricting what `wine` has access to, then anything triggered inside Wine will be forced to listen to that profile.  However, as nothing 'wine' executed runs as root (it actually doesn't let you run wine as root!) it won't be able to touch system files.  AppArmor/SEL rules aren't a default for wine though.

Comment: An `.exe` file to Linux is just binary data since it won't be able to execute it.  This virus isn't a threat to it.  So, it would not have a reason to treat it...  There are Windows-based virus scanners that do what you're suggesting.  These scanners could be used to scan a file within Windows before your execute them.  So...there isn't much of a reason to do what you suggest.  The most valuable part of a virus scanner is the virus definitions and not the scanner itself.  I doubt a Linux-based scanner would have the resources to keep Windows-based definitions up to date...